# Getting inconsistent 500 error - inconsistent Error code 204 on Google App Engine PHP Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

Recently one of our sites got suspended by Google Ads due to "Destination Not Working". When I talked with Google Support they told me that my site is not accessible from all location globally. Then I tried to investigate, the site is hosted on Google App Engine. And I didn't find any 500 errors. But sometimes some website checking tools like "Uptrends" showed me inconsistent error "Http Protocol Error"/500 error. Then I tried to see closely on Google stackdriver logging and ran several tests on Uptrends and on other tools. But I saw something like this.

[image]

And on App Engine logging, I saw something like -

[image]

And also sometimes some HTTP request is not hitting my app so my app logging is not working and it's bothering us so much. We are losing tons of our marketing budget due to this facts. So it would be great if anybody come forward and tell me any clue to test and help me to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> 204s mostly happen because of RAM issue, so boosting to a bigger instance type usually clears these up

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900014

I've gotten a 204 before and it was because there was a memory leak in app engine's ssl library. I was passing it the string to a cert file and it wasn't closing those files. The work-around to fix it was to handle the opening and closing of the file myself and pass it the file handle instead.

If you pay for Google Cloud Support, they may be able to help dig into things that are not visible to you.